# Anti-Diagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices, definition

Hi just a quick question. Can a anti-diagonal have zero in its diagonal? I have this definition in my paper.

*"An anti-diagonal matrix is a square matrix where all the values are zeroes except those 
on the anti-diagonal, i.e. those running from the lower left corner to the upper right 
corner. There is no restriction on what values can appear on the anti-diagonal. "*

The 1st and last line are confusing to whether a zero is valid in the diagonal

Comment: According to the Cambridge dictionary definition of '[except](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/except)', the definition above is self-contradictory. In any case what's probably meant is that a matrix is anti-diagonal if, and only if, all entries which aren't in the anti-diagonal are zero.

Comment: Ok mind blowing. So you mean that its ok to have a zero in the lower left to upper right diagonal right?

Comment: Yes. A quick google search yields links [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) and [2](http://planetmath.org/antidiagonalmatrix) which confirm this.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the counter-identity matrix $J$ Multiplying any matrix $A$ to the left of $J$ results in reversing the rows of $A$, while multiplying $A$ to the right of $J$ results in reversing the columns of $A$.